# Crashes before last loop

Tags: c, arrays, loops

This is a relatively simple program for tabulating grades.

My program crashes while trying to complete the last loop, specifically at the last midterm input. Any help here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ARRAYSIZE 2

int main(void)
{
   char studentID[ARRAYSIZE][10];
   int midterm[ARRAYSIZE];
   int fina[ARRAYSIZE];
   int i=0;
   double overall[ARRAYSIZE];
   for (i=0;i<ARRAYSIZE;i++)
   {
      printf("\nInput Student ID:");
      scanf("%s",&studentID[i][10]);
      printf("\nInput midterm score:");
      scanf("%d",&midterm[i]);
      printf("\nInput final score:");
      scanf("%d",&fina[i]);
      overall[i]=midterm[i]*0.3+fina[i]*0.7;
   }
   printf("\nStudent ID    MidTerm    Final    Overall\n");
   for (i=0;i<ARRAYSIZE;i++)
   {
      printf("%s%5d%5d%5f",studentID[i][10],midterm[i],fina[i],overall[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The process returned is -1073741819 (0xC0000005). Thanks.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&studentID[i][0]);`

Comment: `printf("%s%5d%5d%5f",studentID[i],midterm[i],fina[i],overall[i]);`

Comment: any scanf() will stop when a newline is encountered.  unless the format statement(s) each have a leading ' ' character.  This space char will cause the scanf() to skip over white space (like a newline).

Comment: suggest separating the column titles with a '\t' (tab) character.  this also indicates the printf() format statement would be: "%s\t%5d\t%5d\t%5.2f"

Answer (score 3):

The error is in the final printf statement, specifically 'studentID[i][10]' here you are accessing an element at an illegal index (0 to 9 are legal in your case)

Comment: Also, the type doesn't match with `"%s"` in `printf`.

Comment: @Homer did u mean printf("%s%5d%5d%5f",studentID[i][9],midterm[i],fina[i],overall[i]); will work?

Comment: Absolutely yes, mainly because 'i' is ALSO guaranteed to be less than its maximum!

Answer (score 0):

please try this
//declaration

```
int ARRAYSIZE=2;
char studentID[ARRAYSIZE][10];
```

//Then, you need to enter the string into the array

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
    scanf ("%s" , studentID[i]);
```

}
// in oreder to print them use

```
for (i=0; i<ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
    printf ("%s" , studentID[i]);
```

}